# Set QGIS 2.18.7 on OSX - 10.12 to use GRASS 7

Tags: qgis-plugins, osx, grass-7.0

I read this  [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184152/how-to-set-qgis-2-14-on-os-x-to-use-grass-7/241595?noredirect=1#comment377516_241595), I read this post.
I installed **Qgis 2.18.7** (package maintained by William Kyngesburye), which contains **GASS 7.0.4** with disable **SIP**.

I executed what the post says, but in the "**Grass7Utils.py**" file the specified string was correct. So I did not get any results
[image]

**Grass7** works normally while the Qgis plug-in does not fire and returns the following error:

GRASS init error: GRASS was not found in '/Users/Shared/unix/grass-qgis-mtlion/grass-7.0.4' (GISBASE), provider and plugin will not work.

Do you have any suggestions for this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your Custom paths in Grass Options>General to:

/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass7

Comment: After setting "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass7 " need to install the package "Active States TclTk 8.5.7 (only for TclTk NVIZ in GRASS 6)" and grass 6.4 to http://grassmac.wikidot.com/frameworks, now grass7 working in Qgis 2.18.7 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the problem, in order to use grass on Qgis 2.18.7,also need to install the **Active States TclTk 8.5.7** (only for TclTk NVIZ in GRASS 6) and **Grass 6.4** to the link [this page](http://grassmac.wikidot.com/frameworks), The post can be considered resolved