# GRASS "New Mapset" and "Open Mapset" etc is greyed out

Tags: qgis, shapefile, grass-gis

[image]

All tutorials I have looked at say to just click "New Mapset" to begin a new one but obviously I can't do this to even begin.

I'm not sure if there's something you need to do before creating a new Mapset: I've tried it with a (OS OpenData) map already in QGIS and with a blank page and nothing seems to allow me to click on it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need a GRASS `location` first. I used the GRASS GUI to create one. Then you can open it in the QGIS browser panel.

Comment: Hi. Thankyou. I have downloaded GDAL and all frameworks etc.. On QGIS wxGUI tutorial it says to open GRASS on menu...now, I can see GRASS in QGIS (as above picture shows) but cannot find it in my applications menu. Is it under a different name? I have opened up all frameworks as far as I can tell.

Comment: Seems you are working on a Mac (which I have no experience with). You need GRASS 6 from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/grass or GRASS 7 from https://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/mac-osx/.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your Custom paths in Grass Options>General to:

```
/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass7
```

Steps:
1. Click Plugins;
2. Click GRASS;
3. Click GRASS Options->General ->Custom;
4. Fill in: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass7

Refers to this post: [Set QGIS 2.18.7 on OSX - 10.12 to use GRASS 7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241697/set-qgis-2-18-7-on-osx-10-12-to-use-grass-7)

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2020 / QGIS 3.10.7 LTR

Like Chunli and AndreJ said, you need to update your Custom Path in Pugins > Grass > Grass Options. Here's what mine is set to:

`/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7`

For future Mac users with this issue, you can check the location of `grass7` using the command line. Here's what I did:

```
cd /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/.
find . -name "grass"
```

And here was my result:

```
./Contents/Resources/grass
./Contents/Resources/resources/cpt-city-qgis-min/grass
./Contents/Resources/grass7/etc/python/grass
./Contents/Resources/grass7/etc/colors/grass
./Contents/Resources/grass7/gui/icons/grass
```

That's how I knew to use `/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/grass7` as the path, and it enabled my GRASS options in QGIS.